# Service never gets garbage collected

Tags: android

My application has a button : "Foreground". By clicking on the foreground button, a notification appears attached to a foreground service (started at the time of click). Clicking on my notification is supposed to stop my service (with a PendingIntent) to be able to be garbage collected, however, this is not the case. Android Studio tells me, that there is a reference to my Service held by a NotificationManager. The weird thing is that it only happens if I click on my notification after I closed the main activity.

My service code:

```
public class TestService extends IntentService {
public static final String ACTION_GO_FOREGROUND = "GO_FOREGROUND";
public static final String ACTION_DESTROY = "DESTROY";

private NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;

public TestService() {
    super("Name");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    notificationManager.cancelAll();
    notificationManager = null;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {
        switch (intent.getAction()) {
            case ACTION_GO_FOREGROUND:
                fg();
                break;
            case ACTION_DESTROY:
                destruct();
                break;
        }

    return START_STICKY;
}

private void destruct() {
    stopForeground(true);
    stopSelf();
}

private void fg() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestService.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_DESTROY);

    // Create the notification.
    android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    notificationBuilder.setTicker("Ticker");
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Title");
    notificationBuilder.setContentText("Content text");
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));

    startForeground(1, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

I know the code is messy, but it's just a sample. So why is there a reference to my service, but only if you close the activity and try to destroy the service?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the code from OnDestroy -

```
notificationManager.cancelAll();
notificationManager = null;
```

and place it in destruct() before calling stopSelf()